# Develop c++ application on linux that also works on windows

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I am using eclipse Luna for developing c++ applications. This applications should run on Linux and Windows. Since the program will contain network functions like `getifaddrs` etc. I have to use different stuff for Windows and Linux (which I will already take care in my code).
The question is more, how do I compile the program for Windows environment? Can I set some preferences in eclipse to switch between Linux-compiling and windows-compiling, or is there a generic cross-compiler that works for both?

Would it also be possible to run the application as it would be a windows environment, probably with `wine` to test it?

Comment: You could probably use macros to determine the OS you are on and adjust your program accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that was the plan for the coding part, but I would have to use other #includes such as <winpcap.h>, is it possible to compile it and somehow probably also test it on linux?

Comment: Use the boost libraries.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html  Also, it isn't the OS, it is the compiler.  When you say "work with Windows and Linux", there are several compilers for Windows and several for Linux.

Comment: There are one and a half *billion* machines on this planet that boot Windows.  If you can't find one to compile and test your program then there really isn't any point to this question, it won't work and nobody cares that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the OS sensitive code with preprocessor macros like :

```
#ifdef __PREDEFINED_MACRO_FOR_OS1
// code specific for OS1
#elif __PREDEFINED_MACRO_FOR_OS2
// code specific for OS2
...
#elif _PREDEFINED_MACRO_FOR_OSN
// code specific for OSN
#else 
#error "Operating System not supported."
#endif
```

You can find the specific macros for each OS here : http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

This way the code which is not intended for the current OS will just be ignored and only the right one will be compiled.

Comment: For compiling you should check MinGW that gives you the ability to compile Windows dll and exe under linux. Having this way one single developing and compiling environment.